# Network Adapter not displaying in device manager

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I have an HP Compaq Presario CQ56. All of a sudden my laptop could not even see any WiFi network. I checked my network adapter (**Ralink RT3090 802.11b/g/n**) in device manager only to find out that it has disappeared. Very few times after that, when I put on the system, the network adapter showed up as a useless hidden device. I've tried several tweaks such as cmd's **netsh winsock reset** and **ipconfig/flushdns** but no luck, downloaded and installed the driver but still the same. I've also installed the latest version of windows 10 (2004) but still no luck. Currently, the adapter does not display at all.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZLQ1.png)

What do you think might be the problem?

Comment: `I've also installed the latest version of windows 10 (2004) but still no luck` using W10 for such old devices my be useless for recognizing old hardware as it may lack the drivers

Comment: try to install some hardware soft like AIDA or HWINFO and check if it shows unknown/unrecognized devices, if not, it may be because of [PCB oxidation](http://www.nlcpr.com/AAG_board1.jpg), disassemble the laptop and check the physical device

Comment: Where do I get AIDA and HWINFO?

Comment: Get it with `sudo apt-get -y install hwinfo` on Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: I got them already, but still they do not display my adapters. Guess, I have to open up the device for hardware check.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities. The connectors could be loose, module malfunctioning, was reset to not recognise, OS etc; if possible, would recommend a new USB wifi adapter that's very compatible with equipment of the region. That would probably yield noticeably improved performance cf the wifi adapter it came with too. And the newer adapter would need to be ok with the installed OS, the adapter it came with may not be supported. Good question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the adapter is broken, as reinstalling Windows and the driver had no
effect on the problem.

Try another network adapter, just to be sure, and if it works well then continue
using it instead. Hardware devices are not forever.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you may have tried this solution but just in case you have not:

> Control Panel (Large Icons)
> Network and Sharing Center
> Change Adapter Settings
> When (if) you see your adapter right click and select Disable
> Then right click and select Enable

Whenever my wifi gets hinky this usually does the trick.

Comment: Yes, I"ve tried that as well. The adapter is not visible under Network Connections.